# jboss AS 7.1 application connecting IBM Filenet

Tags: jboss, filenet-p8

Weel am trying to connect to FileNet server on my windows server 2012 Virtual Machine. Evrything works like a charme when am using a standalone java application to do it. But when the connection tentative is done from a Web Application on JBOSS AS 7.1 boom everything is going crazy.

Am getting this exception:

FNRCE0040E: E_NOT_AUTHENTICATED: L'utilisateur n'est pas authentifié. Message : PBOX000070: Password invalid/Password required

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: Where are your logon credentials stored?

Comment: those credentials are stored in wich side ? Filenet or Jboss ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I added the folowing lines to the standalone-full.xml

```
            <security-domain name="FileNetP8WSI" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="com.filenet.api.util.WSILoginModule" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="userName" value="YourUserName"/>
                        <module-option name="password" value="YourPassword"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```